# Контекст YMaps3Parent в React обертке для ymaps API 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Можно ли получить объект карты, при использовании модуля `@yandex/ymaps3-reactify`, из дочерних компонентов, кроме как прокидывать `ref` в компонент `<YMap>`, например, с использованием `YMaps3Parent`, провайдер для которого генерируется в дереве компонентов, чтобы это выглядело примерно так?

```js
const location = {
  center: [37.623082, 55.75254],
  zoom: 14
};

function Map() {
  return (
    <YMap location={location}>
      <MyComponent />
    </YMap>
  )
}

function MyComponent() {
  const map = useContext(YMaps3Parent);

  return /* Некоторая разметка */
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вообще API 3.0 по сути бета-версия. Там ещё многое допиливать должны, многого может не хватать. Но в чём суть вопроса? Есть какая-то сложность выбора нужного объекта карты? А есть код текущей вашей реализации? Насколько он сложнее, чем то, что вы хотите сделать? Да и в целом, какой конечный сценарий?

Comment: Речь идет о том, чтобы сделать собственный компонент добавляемый на карту и иметь доступ к карте, на которую он был добавлен. `YMaps3Parent` в примере потому, что нашел его через инспектор и, для элементов лежащих напрямую в карте, данный контекст содержит ссылку на карту